# Mongoose pass data out of withTransaction helper

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

### Introduction

Hey there,

I am trying to pass out data from the mongoose `withTransaction` callback. Right now, I am using the following code which implements callbacks:

```
const transactionSession = await mongoose.startSession()
await transactionSession.withTransaction(async (tSession) => {
    try {
        // MARK Transaction writes & reads removed for brevity

        console.log("Successfully performed transaction!")
        cb(null, "Any test data")

        return Promise.resolve()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Transaction aborted due to error:", error)
        cb(error)

        return Promise.reject()
    }
})

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return cb(error)
}
```

A more detailed snippet of the `withTransaction` helper in use can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/linus-hologram/0d33e55e079486967f9f4a13c3d26383).

A link to the official Mongoose documentation regarding the `withTransaction` helper can be found [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html).

**At the moment, I am using a callback to pass out data from the `withTransaction`callback:**

`cb(null, "Any test data")`

However, the problem is that naturally the callback is executed first, before the `Promise.resolve()` is returned. This means, that (in my case) a success response is sent back to the client before any necessary database writes are committed:

```
// this is executed first - the callback will send back a response to the client
cb(null, "Any test data")

// only now, after the response already got sent to the client, the transaction is committed.
return Promise.resolve()
```

**Why I think this is a problem:**

Honestly, I am not sure. It just doesn't feel right to send back a success-response to the client, if there hasn't been any database write at that time. Does anybody know the appropriate way to deal with this specific use-case?

I thought about passing data out of the `withTransaction` helper using something like this:

```
const transactionResult = await transactionSession.withTransaction({...})
```

I've tried it, and the response is a `CommandResult` of MongoDB, which does not include any of the data I included in the resolved promise.

### Summary

Is it a problem, if a success response is sent back to the client before the transaction is committed? If so, what is the appropriate way to pass out data from the `withTransaction` helper and thereby committing the transaction *before* sending back a response?

I would be thankful for any advice I get.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like there is some confusion here as to how to correctly use Promises, on several levels.

#### Callback and Promise are being used incorrectly

If the function is supposed to accept a callback, don't return a Promise. If the function is supposed to return a Promise, use the callback given by the Promise:

```
const transactionSession = await mongoose.startSession()
await transactionSession.withTransaction( (tSession) => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        //using Node-style callback
        doSomethingAsync( (err, testData) => {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(testData); //this is the equivalent of cb(null, "Any test data")
            }
        });
    })
```

Let's look at this in more detail:

`return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {` This creates a new Promise, and the Promise is giving you two callbacks to use. `resolve` is a callback to indicate success. You pass it the object you'd like to return. Note that I've removed the `async` keyword (more on this later).

For example:

```
const a = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => resolve(5) );
a.then( (result) => result == 5 ); //true
```

`(err, testData) => {` This function is used to map the Node-style `cb(err, result)` to the Promise's callbacks.

#### Try/catch are being used incorrectly.

Try/catch can only be used for synchronous statements. Let's compare a synchronous call, a Node-style (i.e. `cb(err, result)`) asynchronous callback, a Promise, and using await:

- Synchronous:

```
try {
    let a = doSomethingSync();
} catch(err) {
    handle(err);
}
```

- Async:

```
doSomethingAsync( (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        handle(err);
    } else {
        let a = result;
    }
});
```

- Promise:

```
doSomethingPromisified()
    .then( (result) => { 
        let a = result; 
    })
    .catch( (err) => {
        handle(err);
    });
```

- Await. Await can be used with any function that returns a Promise, and lets you handle the code as if it were synchronous:

```
try {
    let a = await doSomethingPromisified();
} catch(err) {
    handle(err);
}
```

---

### Additional Info

#### `Promise.resolve()`

**`Promise.resolve()`** creates a new Promise and resolves that Promise with an undefined value. This is shorthand for:

```
new Promise( (resolve, reject) => resolve(undefined) );
```

The callback equivalent of this would be:

```
cb(err, undefined);
```

#### `async`

**`async`** goes with **`await`**. If you are using `await` in a function, that function must be declared to be `async`.

Just as `await` unwraps a Promise (`resolve` into a value, and `reject` into an exception), `async` *wraps* code into a Promise. A `return value` statement gets translated into `Promise.resolve(value)`, and a thrown exception `throw e` gets translated into `Promise.reject(e)`.

Consider the following code

```
async () => {
    return doSomethingSync();
}
```

The code above is equivalent to this:

```
() => {
    const p = new Promise(resolve, reject);
    try {
        const value = doSomethingSync();
        p.resolve(value);
    } catch(e) {
        p.reject(e);
    }
    return p;
}
```

If you call either of the above functions without `await`, you will get back a Promise. If you `await` either of them, you will be returned a value, or an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Hey there, thanks a lot for your detailed answer! You are totally right, I am not an expert on JS promises. Could you please tell me what the difference between returning a Promise the way I did and the way you did (with the new Promise(resolve, reject)) is? Both ways tell the withTransaction helper if it worked or not, i.e if database interactions shall be commited or not. Also, how would I now be able to commit the database writes before I send back the response to the client? Could you please provide some example code? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @linus_hologram sure, give me a moment, I'll edit the answer

Comment: @linus_hologram I added some info about `Promise.resolve()`. But I am realising that it would be easier to help you if you gave me more details of the part you edited out

Comment: Hey, sure! I‘ll link a gist, give me a few minutes.

Comment: Hey, please take a look at the updated answer. You can find a link to the gist below the first code snippet :)

Comment: Ok. `await Promise.reject("The refresh token's token-pair document could not be found")` because you are in an `async` block and you `await` this, you are essentially throwing an exception and short-circuiting this code block. Just throw the exception in the if, it will be more obvious what is happening

Comment: Yeah I know that this is something like a short circuit. But isn't that a common (acceptable) way to indicate that something didn't work out?

Comment: (moved to chat)