# Return does wait for two awaits in the same function. JavaSript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Hey guys Im new to nodeJS and mongoDb. So I am having some problems with this code, that seem to work for others people, as it is part of a tutorial, but not for me. The problem is in the function 'followThisUser', I have verified that the return, does not wait until 'following' and 'followed' vars are assigned a value. And it just return them as undefined. If someone could please help me understand why this is happening and also give me a solution I would be very greatfull.

```
async function followThisUser(indentity_user_id, user_id) {
  var following = await Follow.findOne({
    user: indentity_user_id,
    followed: user_id
  }).exec((err, follow) => {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    return follow;
  });

  var followed = await Follow.findOne({
    user: user_id,
    followed: indentity_user_id
  }).exec((err, follow) => {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    return follow;
  })

  return {
    following,
    followed
  }
}

function getUser(req, res) {
  var userId = req.params.id

  User.findById(userId, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send({
      message: 'Error en la petición'
    })
    if (!user) return res.status(404).send({
      message: 'Error el usuario no existe'
    })

    followThisUser(req.user.sub, userId).then((value) => {
      user.password = undefined;
      return res.status(200).send({
        user,
        value
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: No-one here knows what `Follow` or `User` is, or how their implementation might be essential to what you're asking about, so you're not likely to get a response as is.

Comment: @SeanKinsey `Follow` and `User` look like collections to me

Comment: They sure do, but collections that we know work? Collections that have a content that matches the OPs expectations? Right now, it seems like if `undefined`/`undefined` would be the correct result if those collections were for instance empty?

Comment: Add `console.log(follow)` to the `.exec()` callback functions to ensure they're returning something.

Comment: Call `.exec()` without arguments. Handle the error as the rejection that comes from the Promise object returned by `.exec()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is some confusion here regarding the use of `await` here.

My [answer to this Mongoose question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60456059/mongoose-pass-data-out-of-withtransaction-helper/60480108#60480108) may help you understand how `await`, Promises and Node-style callbacks work together.

#### The problem

`findOne` is an asynchronous function.

There are 3 ways to get notified that it is ready to return a value:
1. Take the Promise it returns and use `.then()`

```
Follow.findOne({})
  .then(data => {doSomething()});
```

2. Give `findOne` a callback

```
Follow.findOne({}, (err, data) => {doSomething()});
```

3. Use `.exec()`. this operates like one of the two cases above

You can also use `await` with the Promise-form , instead of `.then()`, e.g.

```
await Follow.findOne({});
doSomething();
```

The problem is that you are both passing a callback and *also* `await`ing a result.

#### Solution

Don't pass callbacks to `.exec()`

```
  var following = await Follow.findOne({
    user: indentity_user_id,
    followed: user_id
  }).exec();

  var followed = await Follow.findOne({
    user: user_id,
    followed: indentity_user_id
  }).exec();
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, `await` only does something useful if you are awaiting a promise.

Second, in mongoose, `model.findOne().exec()` ONLY returns a promise if you do NOT pass a callback to `.exec()`.  If you pass a callback (as you are doing), it communicates completion or error via that callback and there is no promise returned.  Thus your `await` statements are not doing anything.

So, to get promises back from `.exec()` and give the `await` a chance to do something useful, remove the callback from `.exec()`.